# Please translate me my thoughts into mysql

Tags: mysql

im a newbee and an idiot.

I wanna do this:

```
$sql = "SET accountstatus to "1" FROM user WHERE activationlink LIKE '$filename')";
```

- If someone clicks on the `"activationlink"` the `"accountstatus"` from that user should go from "0" to "1".
- `$filename` is a number that is the same as the `"activationlink"` of that user
- i don´t know any MySQL, the string above describes only what i want to do

It would be really nice if someone can help me.

thank you

Comment: Where are you trying to execute the query from? Your SQL seems fairly close to what you need. What do you need help with?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_(SQL)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

See the [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) statement:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user
        SET accountstatus = '1'
        WHERE activationlink = '$filename'";
```

You should also learn how to use prepared statements in PDO or mysqli, rather than substituting variables directly into the SQL.

> i don´t know any MySQL,

Well, if you expect to be able to write applications that work with a database, you'd better learn it quickly. You can't expect us to write all your queries for you.

Comment: :) No, i don´t. I did a view by myself with the help of google search. on this one i hang for 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL that will do what you described:

```
UPDATE user SET accountstatus = "1" WHERE activationlink LIKE '%filename%';
```

filename here is a variable that will need to be defined here. The % is a 2 way match so if your filename contains "december", all rows where the activation link contains "december" will be updated.

Comment: Thank you, "filename" is a random number created by php